# What's a good Silverlight CSV reader?

Tags: silverlight, csv

Does anyone know of a good, quick CSV parser for Silverlight?

Comment: Have you tried searching "c# csv parse"?

Comment: Yes. I found a C# parser I was going to use, but because it wasn't built for Silverlight specifically, it cannot be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the source code, then it does not need to be *Silverlight specific*.

I found these on CodeProject in about 30 seconds using Google:

- [Simple CSV Parser/Reader Function
  Written in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Basic_CSV_Parser_Function.aspx)
- [A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)
- [And one on CodePlex (by StackOverflow member Kent Boogaart)](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/)

You may need to change the way I/O works, but otherwise C# is C#.

*As I have CSV parser experience, from doing product feed processors for large companies, this might be a good little project to publish on our our site. Will give some thought to creating a suitable article.*

Comment: Kent Boogaart added Silverlight support in trunk

Comment: It does not need to be Silverlight specific but you cannot just compile any source for Silverlight. The first link, in particular, uses `ArrayList` which is not available in Silverlight.

Comment: @Xavier Poinas: Given the source code, if the person cannot change an ArrayList to another type that is in Silverlight perhaps they need to consider another career :)