# Parsing CSV files with multiple formats in C# using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have been trying to pass a csv file with three fields. The first two fields are simple and are easily extracted, the problem is with third field which is a string in nature hence can contain special characters including the ',' it self which is used to delimit the fields. I tried containing the string field between two ' " '(double quotes). But my requirement is that for simple string(without special characters) can exist without double quotes. I need to handle the next line in the string also. Below is a sample of a csv file.

> 123,true,This is a memo
>
> 234,false,"This is also a memo"
>
> 345,true,
>
> 456,true,Above me is a blank memo
>
> 567,false,"This has a ,
>
> in it"
>
> 678,true,This has a , in it   <--- This record should be rejected
>
> 789,false,""
>
> 890,true,Above me is also a valid blank memo

I also found a good tool for testing the regex format string at http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Till now I have used the following format string
^(""(?:[^""]|"""")*""|[^,]*),(""(?:[^""]|"""")*""|[^,]*)$

The problem with this format string is that it does not handle multiple lines and does not reject a string with a starting double quote but missing ending double quote.

Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks for the help guys but I needed to parse custom data in CSV and had to create my own custom parser. I am parsing each and every field separately and using regex string in small chunks.

Comment: [Stop Rolling Your Own CSV Parser!](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp)

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to invent this wheel again. I recommend using an existing CSV-parser, but there are many good alternatives.

I have had great success with [CSVReader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader), it's very fast and easy to use. Basic usage:

```
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv"), true))
{
    int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;
    string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();

    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0} = {1};", headers[i], csv[i]));

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your swift reply, but I forgot to mention one thing, I am working on Silverlight and these libraries seems not be available for Silverlight. Do you have any work around for Silverlight?

Comment: @RajatSaini I have not used Silverlight that much so I'm not sure, but they should work for Silverlight to. Maybe this question can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119077/whats-a-good-silverlight-csv-reader

Comment: @RajatSaini: If you're working on SL, why are you trying to parse CSV at client side? It seems to me, more correct way is to make a service, which can parse CSV, and call this service from SL app.

Comment: @Dennis I need to validate as well as convert the CSV to my data model object before making a call to the service.

Comment: @RajatSaini: There are different kinds of validation. The task you described sounds like server validation. You shouldn't perform this conversion at client side.